# How to design a multiuser database?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I'm making an event planning site. In this site, there are going to be many users. Each user will have his own sterile area. 

For example: Each user can create an event, and a list of guests. Now, it could be that two people who created an event would like to invite the same person. I want that person (the guest) to be created twice in the database. Here are my ideas:

#### Multiple databases

I would create a database for each new user, each database would have an identical schema.

#### Prefixed tables

If, for instance, were talking about users 234 and 342, there would be two tables (with the same schema) 234_guests & 342_guests.

#### One table to rule them all

There would be one big guests table, part of the primary key would be a reference to the user that the guest belongs too.

Clarification:
I'll try to clarify my question:
John opens an account with my website. He's planning a wedding for his daughter. Bob also opens an account with my website, he's planning his son's Bar Mitzva. Both Bob and John know a guy named Jim Halpert. Both Bob and John are inviting Jim to their affair. In order to register a guest, you must enter his info. I obviously don't want Bob and John to have access to the same guests (even though they're the same person!), my question is how do I design the database in such an instance.

What's the best, taking into account performance, logic, database normalization?

Are there any other options?

Comment: One database x user? Duplicate the user on the database? I guess you have to spend some more time re-thinking your design. As pointed out on the first answer given, you will end up with lot of unnecessarily duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm gathering here is that you are going to have the following ruling =>

- An Event can have a relationship with multiple Guests.
- Guests can have a relationship with multiple Events.

You could use a Junction table, rather than creating multiple instances of the same person. In theory you could end up duplicating an awful lot of data that way.

The link below demonstrates the benefits of using a Junction Table. They can be used in examples like you have above whereby there Event & Guests have a Many to Many Relationship.

The example in this piece has covers a similar dilemma, Multiple Classrooms & Multiple Students.

http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I may be over simplifying this, but here's how I would go about it:

Create an Event table with fields EventGUID, Location, Date, etc... Then include the EventGUID field in your Guest table. This table could contain the following fields: GuestGUID, EventGUID, Name, Address, etc...

This way, you could have a single table for guests, and they are easily linked back to the event they've been invited to.

In your example, John would have an entry in the Event table, let's say EventGUID='abc' and Bob would have an entry in the Event table, EventGUID='xyz'. There would be two entries in the Guest table for Jim Halpert. The first would have GuestGUID='123' and EventGUID='abc' (this is John's event) and the second would have GuestGUID='456' and EventGUID='xyz' (this is Bob's event).

Using this method would be much cleaner than creating a database or table for each user.